# How do I get visual studio 2017 to see android 7?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

When I load my project I see in the output window

```
    [I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 7.3.0.13
    [I:sdk]:                  Runtime path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
    [I:sdk]:                  Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
    [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_21ab2c5b\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
        Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
    [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_21ab2c5b\Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
        Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b).
    [I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_21ab2c5b\Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
        Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112).
    [I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
    [I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
    [D:]:                     Tracking avd started
    [D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\dpslocal\.android\avd'
    [D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 4 devices
    [W:]:                     Adb connection refused
    [I:]:                     Starting Adb server (adb start-server)
    [I:]:                     Adb start-server operation completed
    [D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 42009f5efe36c337 unauthorized
    [I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
```

Yet when I come to choose the device on which to debug I do not see the latest version, 
only four choices all like android-23_*** (Android 6.0 - API 23)

When I run Android SDK Manager I see that many versions up to 26 (8.0) are installed.

Can someone please advise how to see the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps, hope this can help:

1) Download the Android SDK Manager from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinAndroidSDKManager

2) Install the Android SDK Manager

3) Run it as Administrator you will see the picture below then select which platform you want to install

[image]

Visit this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/using-the-sdk-manager/) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

Go to Visual studio -> tools -> Android -> Android sdk manager. It will ask you to update android sdk to the latest versions.